# How can I move or copy a witch hut into a specific location of my map?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to farm witches because of the resources they provide when killing them. I've watched lot of tutorials on how to farm them but all of them involve using a witch hut that is generated by the world in a swamp. I've tested this in a new creative world and worked as expected. Now I want to do it in my survival world, but the closest witch hut to my house is very far. I wonder if I can modify my map to "move" or "clone" this witch hut closer to my buildings so I can retrieve the materials easily and to not travel a lot just to check if I have enough redstone or other things. I've read that you can do it with McEdit but not sure how this works.

Additional info: I'm playing Minecraft 1.11.2 on a MacBook Pro macOS Sierra.

Comment: Alternatively you could build a nether portal at each location to switch faster from your home and the witchhouse. Or you could build a railroad for minecarts.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you're trying to do:

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/discussion/2147218-tutorial-how-to-move-a-swamp-hut-also-called-witch

The general gist of that is to edit the Temples.dat file which is where the witch huts are saved.  This is done with a program called NBTEdit.

Answer (score -2):

You could use program called mcedit: http://www.mcedit.net/
I don't know how to move something in it.
But I know that you can move something.
There are a lot of tutorials how to do it on youtube.